# how to Log-linear this equation?

Tags: macroeconomics, dsge, log-linearization

I am working on my thesis, doing a model with energy price. I am following this paper "Energy Price Shocks and Financial Market Integration: Evidence from New Keynesian Model", Tarek Ghazouani, 2020.

I have been having troubles in log-linearizing with this equation, which is given by
[image]

è stata ottenuta massimizzando il vincolo di bilancio rispetto Ft
[image]
[image]

These two equations are also introduced but I can't understand how they are used
[image]

I would appreciate very much any help.

Alessia

Comment: What specific problem with log-linearization you have? Just literally take natural log of both sides.

Comment: I know that it is not so easy, I know it's not that simple, it's necessary then express in percentage deviation from the steady state. I generally apply this formula: (f'(x)*x/f(x))*xlog, respect every variable, so I was wondering if my calculations are right and where did that equation come from